# Roku works but is not apparently on our network?

Tags: arp, netstat

We have two Roku devices in our house.  Each is connected to a different TV's HDMI port and both work.  They have unused RJ-11 ports, so I expect them to be on WiFi.  But neither appears in the outputs of `netstat -rn` & `arp -a`.  Why is that?  Would a router typically hide them from a laptop?

Comment: I have no explanation, but I ran a scanner app that found both Roku immediately after the shell commands didn't.  And about an hour later, did `arp -a` again and it also found them.

Comment: While not relevant to your issue, just an FYI: IoT and media devices (TVs, Rokus, ChromeCast, etc.) should always be on a separate vLAN if the router supports this, else the Guest network if it doesn't, as they should always remain firewalled from LAN devices (PCs, NAS, etc.).

Comment: @JW0914, thanks!  As a retired software engineer, I _should_have_ already thought of that!!

Comment: A lot of users either don't know, or simply forget, to move _all_ IoT devices _(incl. Nest, Echo, Bixby, etc. devices)_ to a separate network firewalled from LAN, and it's gotten to the point the FBI issued a [briefing](https://www.fbi.gov/contact-us/field-offices/portland/news/press-releases/tech-tuesday-internet-of-things-iot) on 2019.12.03 imploring users to do so, with [Forbes](https://www.forbes.com/sites/zakdoffman/2019/12/06/dont-get-hacked-warns-fbi-this-is-how-you-connect-smart-devices/#4d719394360a) also elaborating on the briefing.